# Hahn Banach to get linear functional bounded by sub/superlinear functionals

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

I am working in a real vector space $V$. I have seen it written that if I have a sublinear functional $p$ and a superlinear functional $q$ such that $q \le p$ then there exists some linear functional $q \le f \le p$. How can I prove this?

I could easily get $-p(-x) \le f(x) \le p(x)$ but I can't seem to convert this (or related results) to the desired form.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.academia.edu/3650586/Hahn_-_Banach_theorem_for_finite_numbers_of_sublinear_and_superlinear_functionals) paper claims it is false and gives a counter-example (example 3.1 in page 9).